# How do I know if this Motherboard will fit in the case?

Tags: motherboard

I have ordered [this Zalman T4 case](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00G4E60SW)
along with this [Asus H81M-E motherboard](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00EIGWTIS) but now I am not sure if the MB will fit inside the case. 
I have searched for the internal dimensions of the case online but couldn't find anything anywhere.

Does anyone know if the MB will fit?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Asus H81M-E product page](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/H81ME/#specifications):

> uATX Form Factor
>   8.9 inch x 6.9 inch ( 22.6 cm x 17.5 cm )

From the [Zalman T4 product page](http://www.zalman.co.kr/global/product/Product_Read.php?Idx=835):

> Efficient layout allows the installation of Micro-ATX/Mini ITX main board
>   and VGA/PSU/ODD, despite of its slim design.
>
> Motherboards
>   Micro ATX / Mini ITX

---

[uATX is the same as Micro ATX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MicroATX). So based on these specifications, it fits.

Note that other components might also be an issue, like large graphics cards, or above the CPU (tower cooler and possible window fan).

Answer (score 0):

There are three general sizes of cases and motherboards. In order from biggest to smallest:

- ATX
- Micro ATX / mATX
- Mini ITX / mITX

A smaller motherboard will generally fit inside a larger case, but not the other way around.

From the description of your case

> Efficient layout allows the installation of **Micro-ATX**/Mini ITX main board and VGA/PSU/ODD, despite of its slim design. 250mm to 300mm high performance VGA card can be installed. Anti-slip rubber at the bottom of the case and the PSU helps to eliminate vibration sound. <

(emphasis mine) it **will** fit the Micro-ATX board you listed. You may have trouble fitting after-market heatsinks (especially the tower variety that are common with with power users), although the standard heatsink/fan and most slimline ones should work well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, you possibly should add E-ATX to your list; this format is widely used for workstation and server mainboards, and many of the bigger cases (e.g. the longer variants of 19" cases and the bigger variants of midi cases) can take this format. The position of the screw holes is standardized.